# How to force all traffic for a Linux user group on one interface

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking, terminal-server

We are running a Linux Mint 20.2 terminal server using [ThinLinc's Remote Desktop](https://www.cendio.com/). A bit unconventionally, we set the primary group for all users as either 'staff' or 'students.' We need to give the 'staff' group unfiltered internet access (via device enp1s0) straight through the LAN gateway. We need to give the 'students' group filtered access (via device enp1s0.20) on a vlan through a pfSense gateway. The unfiltered access works fine; disabling enp1s0 and sending all traffic out through the filtered gateway works as expected. We can also block the student group with this iptables rule:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport  80,443 -m owner --gid-owner "students" -j DROP
```

But I haven't discovered how to force 'students' traffic out the vlan with both interfaces enabled.

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I spent many (way too many!) hours researching and exploring different solutions before posting here, but wouldn't you know, I found my own answer less than an hour later. [Intika's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface/498140#498140) to a different question finally headed me in the [right direction](https://blog.sebastien.raveau.name/2009/04/per-process-routing.html). I'm sure there are solutions with network namespaces, etc., but this was by far the simplest way to achieve our desired end.

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner "students" -j MARK --set-mark 42
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0.20 -m mark --mark 42 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.20.10
ip rule add fwmark 42 table 42
ip route add default via 192.168.20.2 dev enp1s0.20 table 42
netfilter-persistent save
```

The vlan IP is 192.168.20.10; the filtered gateway is 192.168.20.2.

**NOTE 1: iptables-save does not make this persistent over reboots**; only netfilter-persistent will save the iptables changes.

**NOTE 2: This doesn't save the ip route configuration.** This needs to be set to reload any time the interface is reactivated (unplugged cable, reboot, etc.). To make this configuration persistent, you need to configure the appropriate file in /etc/netplan. Since I wasn't able to parse the syntax or find relevant examples, I've appended the original iptables `-j DROP` rule and saved this (with netfilter-persistent) so that in the event of an unattended network reset, all student access will be blocked. Then I've written a very simple script removing that line from the Filter table, and adding the `ip route` line again.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Remove the permanent block on Group 'students' from the Filter table: sudo iptables -D OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport  80,443 -m owner --gid-owner "students" -j DROP
# Add the route policies that don't persist over a network restart without editing the netplan config:
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.20.2 dev enp1s0.20 table 42
echo "Filtered Access should be configured for Group 'students'"
exit
```